# Why is this for loop returning the index of a character and not the whole property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

```
var options = {
fieldsToValidate : {},  
slideDowns : {
    0: '#address-phone-block',
    1: '#zip-dob-block',
    2: '#nextButton'
},
continueButton: "#continue-button",
landingForm: '#landingForm'
}

for (var slider in options.slideDowns[]){
    console.log('did this work?' , slider , options.continueButton[slider])
    $(options.continueButton[slider]).slideDown();  
}
```

When the console logs i get this output, and then this error on the jQuery selector:

```
did this work? 0 #
"Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #"
```

I know that slider is 0/1/2 so why is this giving me the first character of the first property?

Comment: What happens if you just log `options.continueButton` instead of `options.continueButton[slider]`?

Comment: The answer below seems to solve your problem, but regarding the actual question in your title: javascript `for` loops *always* return the index, not the actual property. That's just how they work!
Also: you shouldn't have those `[]` after `slideDowns`.

Comment: Yeah, in hindsight i should have really looked at this a bit more intently rather than posting it here, everything is working as intended now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `options.continueButton` is `String` with '`#continue-button`' value, so `options.continueButton[0]` is its first character, which is '`#`'.

Probably you need to use `options.slideDowns` instead of `options.continueButton`, as you are looping through its properties:

```
for (var slider in options.slideDowns){
    console.log('did this work?' , slider , options.slideDowns[slider])
    $(options.slideDowns[slider]).slideDown();  
}
```

Comment: #facepalm OMG how did i not see i was referencing the continueButton property and not the slideDowns property >.<